# Create a template to read different type of Point Clouds

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have created a template function to read PointXYZ and PointXYZI cloud. I can also read PointXYZRGB cloud with further addition.  However, this way I guess the code will be much longer to accomodate other types. Could you suggest a better solution.

The code is as below

```
template <typename T>
typename T::Ptr readGeneralPointCloud( const std::string & filename ,  std::function<typename T::PointType( const std::string & )> storage_function )
{   
std::ifstream input;
input.open( filename );

if( ! input.fail() )
{
    typename T::Ptr pointCloud( new T);
    std::string content;

    while( std::getline( input , content ) )
    {
        pointCloud->points.push_back( storage_function( content ) );
    }

    return pointCloud;
}
else
{
    throw std::exception( "Error occured : The file cannot be opened and the returned cloud is an empty cloud " );
    return typename T::Ptr( new typename T() );
}
}

template <typename T>
T readPointCloud( const std::string &filename ){}

// Explicit template instantiation
template <>
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr readPointCloud( const std::string & filename ) 
{
return readGeneralPointCloud<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>>
(
    filename ,
    [] ( const std::string & someStr ) -> pcl::PointXYZI
    {
        std::istringstream s( someStr );
        std::vector<std::string> separated_tokens{ std::istream_iterator < std::string > {s} , std::istream_iterator < std::string > {} };

        if( separated_tokens.size() != 4 )
        {
            throw  std::exception( "Exception occured: The data of PointXYZI cloud should be  4" );
        }

        auto tmp = separated_tokens.cbegin();
        pcl::PointXYZI xyzi_points;

        try
        {
            xyzi_points.x = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            xyzi_points.y = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            xyzi_points.z = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            xyzi_points.intensity = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            return xyzi_points;
        }
        catch( const boost::bad_lexical_cast e )
        {
            throw std::exception( "Error Occured: The data couldn't be converted to double, possibly bad format of data" );
        }
    }
);
}

template <>
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr readPointCloud( const std::string & filename )
{
return readGeneralPointCloud<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>
(
    filename ,
    [] ( const std::string & someStr ) -> pcl::PointXYZ
    {
        std::istringstream s( someStr );
        std::vector<std::string> separated_tokens{ std::istream_iterator < std::string > {s} , std::istream_iterator < std::string > {} };

        if( separated_tokens.size() != 3 )
        {
            throw  std::exception( "Exception occured: The number of data of PointXYZ cloud should be  3" );
        }

        auto tmp = separated_tokens.cbegin();
        pcl::PointXYZ xyz_points;

        try
        {
            xyz_points.x = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            xyz_points.y = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            xyz_points.z = boost::lexical_cast< double >( *tmp++ );
            return xyz_points;
        }
        catch( const boost::bad_lexical_cast e )
        {
            throw std::exception( "Error Occured: The data couldn't be converted to double, possibly bad format of data" );
        }
    }
);
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the motivation for not using pcl::io::loadPCDFile? ( http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php ). Note that you can load any cloud into a PointCloud2 object. ( http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/group__io.html#ga423c81afbdce67da03c94c221c4500b4 )

Comment: @D.J.Duff There are hundreds of Point Cloud fomat data converted to .txt or other format  file. I have to create an application to read those files. This program should allow the user to read those data. I am not allowed to change the data to pcd format. So, I have to leave it as it is.